# Drawing a border using a custom view Android

Tags: android, custom-view

I'm trying to draw a custom border by drawing a custom view.  Here is a sample of one side of the border:

```
package com.sparkydev.guessaphrase;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RectShape;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class LeftBorder extends View {
    private ShapeDrawable vertRect, horizRect;

    public LeftBorder(Context context, AttributeSet attributeset) {
        super(context, attributeset);

        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();

        vertRect = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
            vertRect.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
            vertRect.setBounds(0, 0, width/10, height);
        horizRect = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
            horizRect.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
            horizRect.setBounds(0, 0, width, height/9);

    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        vertRect.draw(canvas);
        horizRect.draw(canvas);
    }

}
```

And the other side is defined pretty much the same way.  The XML is defined as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/wallpaper">


    <!-- Declares left border's position, which is
    drawn programmatically.-->
    <com.sparkydev.guessaphrase.LeftBorder
        android:id="@+id/leftborder"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />



        <!-- Used a FrameLayout to contain
        the menu buttons.-->
        <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

            <!-- Menu buttons -->

        </FrameLayout>


    <!-- Declares right border position (on right
    of screen, below the left border) -->
    <com.sparkydev.guessaphrase.RightBorder
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/leftborder"
    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, the borders are not showing up at all.  The background shows, but nothing else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [the "Building Custom Components" dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#custom), when creating a custom view, it will have a set size of 100x100 until you specify otherwise. See if this has anything to do with the issue you are seeing.

> "You will almost certainly want to override `onMeasure()` and are also likely to need to override `onDraw()` if you want the component to show something. While both have default behavior, the default `onDraw()` will do nothing, and the default `onMeasure()` will always set a size of 100x100 — which is probably not what you want."

Comment: Hooray!  Thank you.  I would vote your answer up, but I don't have high enough reputation.

Comment: In lieu of that you can mark the answer as the accepted answer if it solves the problem. ;-)